# R: "Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xC9 0x74 0x61 0x74"

Tags: r, utf-8

Using the gmapsdistance package i tried to run a simple line of code:

```
results=gmapsdistance("Chicago+IL","New+York+City+NY","walking","myapicode")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xC9 0x74 0x61 0x74
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in a direction to help solve my problem.

Comment: I arrived here because I just ran into the same problem, and haven't solved it yet. But I comment just to encourage you to remove your API key from your original post as it could be used to run-up usage on your Google service.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens I determined that this problem was from the fact that the package requires Mac OS.  I was using Windows.

Comment: Actually, I discovered the problem is a bug in the package in the part of the function that forms the URL. If you remove the unnecessary pipe characters ("|") from the constructed URL it works fine.  I rewrote the function and emailed the package author to see if he'd like to incorporate the fix.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens of course, it's still in the edit history. Flagging a moderator to try and remove it permanently...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thanks for your post. I am the maintainer of the gmapsdistance package. I received a couple of e-mails with this bug for Windows users. I fixed and submitted it to CRAN again. If it is not yet up in CRAN you can install the most updated version from the github website:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rodazuero/gmapsdistance")
```

Please, let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: I am having a different issue on a Windows machine. When I run the OP's code with my API key, it's fine. But when I change the mode to `driving`, I get: `Error in rowXML[[dur]] : subscript out of bounds`. Taking the key out lets it work though.

Comment: NIce! I had the same problem but now with the update it's working

Comment: Similar to Albert, my issue was also solved. But there is another issue when the origin or destination have accented characters:
`> gmapsdistance(origin = "Maceió", destination = "Aracaju", mode = "driving")
Error in gmapsdistance(origin = "Maceió", destination = "Aracaju", mode = "driving") : 
  Google API returned an error: Invalid request. Invalid 'origins' parameter.`